# How to keep the database updated when the user enters new values in android studio?

Tags: android

I'm dealing with a simple app, which basically stores various dates. But when I enter a new date, I have to close the app and open it again. The same thing counts for changing the date values. I can only see the changes by closing the app and reopening it.
Here are the two main functions in my DB class;

```
public void addBirthday(Person person){  //Add a data to database
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(column_name, person.getName());
    cv.put(column_sname, person.getSname());
    cv.put(column_day, person.getDay());
    cv.put(column_month, person.getMonth());
    cv.put(column_year, person.getYear());

    db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
    db.close();
}

public int updateBirthday(Person person) {

    // 1. get reference to writable DB
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    // 2. create ContentValues to add key "column"/value
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

    cv.put(column_name, person.getName());
    cv.put(column_sname, person.getSname());
    cv.put(column_day, person.getDay());
    cv.put(column_month, person.getMonth());
    cv.put(column_year, person.getYear());

    // 3. updating row
    int i = db.update(TABLE_NAME, //table
            cv, // column/value
            column_id +" = ?", // selections
            new String[] { String.valueOf(person.getId()) }); //selection args

    // 4. close
    db.close();

    return i;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to refresh the view (probably a `ListView`) where you display this data.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the notifyDataSetChanged() and call requery() on your Cursor